# Pass dynamic parameter as data to route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I'm currently trying to pass data inside of my Angular Routing. Since it's dynamic, I want to pass the parameter `:name` to the route (in this case `data: {breadcrump: ...`) - how can I do so?

```
{path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent, data: {breadcrump: 'Produkte'}, children: [
  {path: '', data: {breadcrump: null}, component: ProductOverviewComponent},
  {path: ':name', data: {breadcrump: 'Test'}, component: ProductPageComponent},
]},
```

```
export class ProductsBreadcrumpComponent implements OnInit {

  menuItems;

  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.menuItems = this.createBreadcrumbs(this.activatedRoute.root);
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(() => this.menuItems = this.createBreadcrumbs(this.activatedRoute.root));
  }

  createBreadcrumbs(route: ActivatedRoute, url: string = '', breadcrumbs: MenuItem[] = []): MenuItem[] {
    const children: ActivatedRoute[] = route.children;

    if (children.length === 0) {
      return breadcrumbs;
    }

    for (const child of children) {
      const routeURL: string = child.snapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join('/');
      if (routeURL !== '') {
        url += `/${routeURL}`;
        console.log(url);
      }

      const label = child.snapshot.data.breadcrump;
      if (label) {
        breadcrumbs.push({label, url});
      }

      return this.createBreadcrumbs(child, url, breadcrumbs);
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: show us the TS code where are you working with breadcrumb

Comment: @RomanŠimík Alright, thanks - see edit.

Comment: In the `route` param in `createBreadcrumbs()` func should be somewhere stored that information (I think it should be `route.params.name`).